How to fix Secure Boot error "Image failed to verify with *ACCESS DENIED*"
When attempting to boot a live OS via USB or CD, I get the secure boot error: "Image failed to verify with ACCESS DENIED".

There is no SSD/HDD installed. Secure Boot is enabled and while I know that disabling Secure Boot will allow me to boot to the live OS, disabling secure boot will also allow any nasty malware to initialize and run affecting the OS as it's being loaded into memory. I believe strongly that my firmware is infected, preventing live OS's from booting. The device is a Lenovo Thinkpad W541.
